# VisualForce page for new custom object

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I am a newbie in this field. First time trying to code a VisualForce page.

I have created a custom object named 'Order'. Added one custom field named 'Account' which is referencing to an account object.
I would like to override the default New button with my own VF page.

This is my controller code:

```
public class orderExtension {

  private final Order__c order;

  public orderExtension (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    order = (Order__c) stdController.getRecord();
  }
}
```

This is my VF page code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Order__c" extensions="orderExtension">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Order Edit" subtitle="New Order"/>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Order Edit" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save and Add Products" action="{!save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Order Information" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField label="Account" value="????"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Could you please assist me with the inputField? Code samples will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Liora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple :)

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Account__c}"/>
```

But maybe better will be to modify it a bit. Change the definition of `order` variable in apex to this:

```
public Order__c order {get;set;}
```

I'm not sure why you marked it as private (= can't be changed from Visualforce) and final (used rather in places where you don't want to change something at all).

And then in Visualforce you can refer to it like that:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!order.Account__c}"/>
```